# Python - Mailchimp Batch PUT requests

Tags: python, python-requests, mailchimp

I'm trying to use the batch functionality for the Mailchimp API. My current set up is like this

```
operations = []
for idx, row in users_df.iterows():
    payload = {
        'email': row['email'],
        'last_updated': row['new_time'],
        'custom_value': row['new_value']
    }
    operation_item = {
        "method": "POST", # I changed this to PUT
        "path": '/lists/members/12345',
        "body": json.dumps(payload),
    }
    operations.append(operation_item)
client = mc.MailChimp(MAILCHIMP_TOKEN, MAILCHIMP_USER)
batch = client.batches.create(data={"operations": operations})
```

Whenever I use the POST method I get this error: `old_user@gmail.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members.`

But whenever I change my method to PUT, I get this other error: `The requested method and resource are not compatible. See the Allow header for this resource's available methods.`

Is there a way to overcome this? I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828112/python-adding-subscribers-to-mailchimp-with-bulk-api-v3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021727/httparty-to-batch-update-users-on-mailchimp-3-0-api) is a similar problem in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do PUT to the list resource `"/lists/members/12345"`, you need to change path to be `"/lists/members/12345/{email}"`

this code works for us:

```
def add_users_to_mailchimp_list(list_id, users):
operations = []
client = get_mailchimp_client()

for user in users:
    member = {
        'email_address': user.email,
        'status_if_new': 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields': {
            'FNAME': user.first_name or '',
            'LNAME': user.last_name or '',
        },
    }
    operation_item = {
        "method": "PUT",
        "path": client.lists.members._build_path(list_id, 'members', user.email),
        "body": json.dumps(member),
    }
    operations.append(operation_item)
return client.batches.create(data={"operations": operations})
```

using protected method `client.lists.members._build_path` is a bit hacky I guess, if you like you can build the url manually, it will be `f'lists/{list_id}/members/{user.email}'`